# Oracle: How to add Check Constraint Date Column greater or equals to today

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to add a check constraint on a column in `Oracle 12C`:

How do I add Check Constraint so that the date entered is Greater or Equals to today. I tried the code below but getting an error:

Note: The `BEGIN_DATE` Column is a `TIMESTAMP` data type:
Code:

```
  ALTER TABLE DBMS.PERSON
  ADD CONSTRAINT CK_BEGIN_DATE_PERSON
    CHECK(
          TRUNC(BEGIN_DATE) >= SYSDATE
         );
```

Comment: I feel that the answer provided is too extraneous and it puts a lot of burden on the DB. And also, because I am working with 12C, perhaps there is a simpler way to check a date. Not all answers are better solutions, which is what I am hoping for.

Comment: Perhaps take a step back and think again about why you think you need a constraint that is not always true.